# schemadb: get latest insert ID

Tags: php, mysql, database-schema

I need to retrieve last insert ID of a specific record after ->store() metrod on schemadb 
read more here https://sourceforge.net/p/schemadb/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should use:

```
echo schemadb_action('last_id');
```

Comment: what think about schemadb? Into MVC avoid the manual table creation and schema definition...